Which bundler is Next.js 14.2.11 using?
I have a created a Next.js project with npx create-next-app@latest
It is using Next.js 14.2.11 with typescript.
I am not able to understand which bundler it is using. I am not seeing Webpack/Turbo in the package-lock.json.
How to know which bundler is used? Or webpack is somehow internally mapped in Next.js?
